# Extend / override Meteor blaze template from packages

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework, meteor-blaze

I use the useraccounts:ionic package and I would like to add a line to the beginning of one of its templates.

I know that I can get the repo from GitHub and then use it in my project, but I would rather keep using it through "meteor add".

Is it possible to change or "override" individual templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options for you:

- Check out the 'aldeed:template-extension' package; it exports a 'replaces(templateName)' method that will do what you want.
- Implement your own override method like this:

  ```
  //
  // Helper shim to override template renderFunctions
  // Inspired by replaces() from aldeed:template-extension package. Good stuff.
  Template.prototype._override = function (replacement){
      if (typeof replacement === 'string') {
          replacement = Template[replacement];
      }
      if (replacement && replacement instanceof Blaze.Template ) {
          this.renderFunction = replacement.renderFunction;
      }
  }

  ...

  Template.someTemplateILike._override('myReplacementTemplate');
  ```

--
kobi